# PHP: Convert Day of Year to Day of Month and Month

Tags: php, date, timestamp

If you have the day of the year. How can you convert that to day of month and month? For example: The day "144" should be converted to 26th of May. I guess I also have to add the actual year to account for leap years. But I haven't found anything at all.

For example the function [mktime()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mktime.php) exepects the month, year and day of month.

Anybody some suggestions?

Comment: It depends if this a leap year or not.

Comment: btw. today is 147th day of 2012 ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
strtotime("January 1st +".($days-1)." days");
```

This will return a timestamp corresponding to the specified day of the year.

Answer (score 11):

The most reliable and convenient way is to use the DateTime object. You can use [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) static method to create it based on day in the current year:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('z', '144');
```

And because you know have DateTime object in the `$date` variable, you can perform literally any task you want to. To output the contained date, simply call:

```
echo $date->format('j. n. Y');
```

It will print out 24. 5. 2012, because it's leap year and because it indexes days starting from zero (just like array indices).