# i want convert integer number to date in year in php

Tags: php, date, timestamp, integer, numbers

I want to convert the number of year to date
for example in number 76 in 2021 is 17-3

$d = 76;
$x = substr($d, 0, 4) .'-'. substr($d, 4,2) .'-'. substr($d,6,2) .' '. substr($d,8,2) .':'. substr($d,10,2) .':'. substr($d,12,2);
echo $x;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: Convert Day of Year to Day of Month and Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769830/php-convert-day-of-year-to-day-of-month-and-month)

Answer (score 0):

You can use add,

```
        $date = new DateTime("2021");
        $days = 76;
        $date->add(new DateInterval("P${days}D"));
        echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` is the most obvious solution for your task:

```
$result = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2021-01-00 +76 day'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The number 76 for the date 17-3 is the day of the year starting with 1. Some solutions with DateTime.

For the current year:

```
$dayOfYear = 76;  //starting from 1
$dateTime = date_create('Jan 1 +'.($dayOfYear-1).' Days');

echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //2021-03-17 00:00:00
```

Alternatively, the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769830/php-convert-day-of-year-to-day-of-month-and-month), changed for the day of the year from 1 and to get the time 00:00.

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:sz', "00:00:00".($dayOfYear-1));
```

If you want to use a fixed year:

```
$dateTime = date_create('2021-01-01 +'.($dayOfYear-1).' Days');
```